# Get the IP address of Device connected

Tags: c#, webapi

I have this method in C# API that is returning the IP of the device connected:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return IP address
    /// </summary>
    private string GetIP()
    {
        string IPAddress = "";
        string Hostname = Environment.MachineName;
        IPHostEntry Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Hostname);
        foreach (IPAddress IP in Host.AddressList)
        {
            if (IP.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                IPAddress = Convert.ToString(IP);
            }
        }
        return IPAddress;
    }
```

But in Azure, this end up grabbing the wrong IP address beause of appgateaway. How I can modify it to get the connect IP and also how to have this in BaseAPIController.

Comment: this is looking up your IP adrress not the connected node

Comment: @pm100 how get the IP of connected node?

Comment: Is this a web server or are you doing your own socket connections

Comment: @pm100 - web server

Comment: ok look at all the headers you are receiving from the client - the app gateway will have added a header , something like x-msft-originip